# Legendary Dwellers in the beginning of the game

Tags: fallout-shelter

I was wondering if it is possible to get a Legendary Dweller in one of the 4 "introductory" lunch boxes in the beginning of the game. I've restarted my vault about 50 times, maybe more, and have yet to get one.

Comment: By legendary, you mean any of the [special ones](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_characters)?

Comment: The page you have linked for "the special ones" refers to them as "Legendary Characters" no less than two times. ;)

Comment: If by special you mean the ones that are better than normal dwellers, but aren't quite as good as legendary, I have gotten quite a few of those. I'm talking about ones from the 21 in the sticker book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible and it is random, so you were not lucky if you did restart 50 times and got none of the [special dwellers](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_characters).

On my second vault, I got [Star Paladin Cross](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cross) from one of the lunch boxes of the tutorial.

Comment: This confirms my experience as well, but that was back at iOS launch.

Comment: I had a bunch of luck on iOS, absolutely none on Android. I really feel that Bethesda is trolling Android users :)

Comment: Reacieved a legendary within the starters for my second vault, on android.

Comment: I received Preston Garvey as well (lvl 45) on Android.